# jquery Validation diffifculty in handling the behavior for multiple sections in a single form

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I have a form with multiple sections, and i am not able to handle the behavior of the validation of sections within a single form independently.

In this example, http://jsbin.com/ojihiv/4/edit , I have 2 sections, in section 1, i need to achieve display error message at an section, in section 2, i need to achieve display of error message as title of the input element.

Issue with the example is, always the first selected behavior will be applied there after. This can be tested as below.

Case 1: Click validateemail without entering data, section level error message is displayed and now click on validatename now the error message was supposed to display as title, where as it displays as the section.

Refresh the page

Case 2: Click validatename without entering data, error message is displayed as title and now click on validateemail the error message was supposed to display as section , where as it displays error as title.

Could some one help me please.

Comment: I am in need to know answer for this :(

Answer (score 1):

put text box in div tag.

I have given a example for validation, error msg will display in "closest" div.

```
$("#prRegistration").validate({
   rules: {
        user_name: { 
            required: true, minlength: 2
        }
    },

    messages: {
        user_name: {
            required :"Please enter first name"
            // minlength:""
        }
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {error.insertAfter(element.closest("div"));}
});
```

Comment: this would have solved my problem if i have to display error message in same style across the sections, my requirement is to display error message  in different styles in different section. i.e, display error message as section level  message in section1 and display as title in section 2